# Call to undefined function dl() error w/Joomla 3.5.1 & PHP 7

Tags: joomla, php, evaluating-civicrm, security, php7

I've just installed CiviCRM on a Joomla 3.5.1 site to learn how to use it.
I am seeing an issue that I have a question about.

As long as I use Php 5.6 the installation works properly. If I try to use Php 7 everything on the Joomla site works except Civicrm. From the backend if I select Civicrm I get this error:  *Call to undefined function dl()*

As soon as I go back to Php5.x all is well. The database is using utf8mb4_general_ci collation and mysqli.

Is there anything that needs to be done to use Php7 that I haven't found?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I learned that php7 is not supported yet.

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviCRM+PHP+Requirements